# Serial communication to Android device from Nano via Bluetooth delay too high

Tags: android, bluetooth, delay

i'm having difficulty sending serial data from my Arduino nano to my android app i have made. The serial monitor shows the correct output regardless of the delay used. However the android device will not receive-with consistency-any data without at least a delay of 800. Can anyone please explain this to me, as i'm at a loss.

The app is developed on MIT app inventor and works fine.

Many thanks in advance. Here's my code.

```
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo 


const int mcbpos  = 3;        //the pin that will sense the position of the MCB
const int tamper  = 4;        // the number of the tamper button pin
const int reset   = 5;        // the pin number of the reset button
const int emstop  = 6;        //the pin that will sense the emergency stop button

const int onled   = 11;      // the number of the on led pin
const int offled  = 12;      // the number of the off led pin
const int tamled  = 13;      // the numbr of the Tamper input

int i   = 0;
int pos = 0;              // variable to store the servo position 
int tam = 0;              // variable to store tamper switch status
int res = 0;              // variable to store reset switch status
int ems = 0;              // variable to store emergency stop status
int mcb = 0;
byte serialA;             //sets up the serial connection to the App

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600); //Setting up the Baud rate for the Bluetooth connection

  pinMode(mcbpos,INPUT);  //initialise mcb position sensor
  pinMode(tamper,INPUT);  //initialize the tamper switch as an input
  pinMode(reset,INPUT);    // initialise the reset button
  pinMode(emstop, INPUT); //  initialize the emergency stop pin as an intput

  pinMode(tamled, OUTPUT); // initialize the tamper LED pin as an output     
  pinMode(onled, OUTPUT); // initialize the ON LED pin as an output:   
  pinMode(offled, OUTPUT); //initialise the OFFLED as an output
  myservo.attach(9);      // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object 
}

int onsub()                              //sets up the subroutine for moving the servo       to the on position
{
  for(pos = 90; pos > 50; pos -= 1)  // goes from 110 degrees to 135 degrees 
 {                                  // in steps of 1 degree 
  myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
 delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
 } 
 for(pos = 50; pos < 120; pos += 1)  // goes from 110 degrees to 135 degrees 
 {                                  // in steps of 1 degree 
  myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
  delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
} 
for(pos = 120; pos>=90; pos-=1)     // goes from 135 degrees to 110 degrees 
{                                
myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
} 
}

int offsub()                          //sets up the subroutine for moving the servo to         the off position
{
for(pos = 80; pos>=50; pos-=1)     // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees 
{                                
myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
} 
for(pos = 50; pos < 80; pos += 1)  // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees 
{                                  // in steps of 1 degree 
myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
} 
}

void loop()
{

mcb = digitalRead(mcbpos);  //assign mcb position to variable mcb
tam = digitalRead(tamper);  //assign tamper signal position to variable tam
res = digitalRead(reset);  //assign reset switch position to variable res
ems = digitalRead(emstop);  //assign emergency stop switch position to variable ems

 digitalWrite(mcbpos, HIGH);    //Setting the pull up resistors for the swithches
digitalWrite(tamper, HIGH);    //Setting the pull up resistors for the swithches
digitalWrite(reset, HIGH);     //Setting the pull up resistors for the swithches
digitalWrite(emstop, HIGH);    //Setting the pull up resistors for the swithches


if (Serial.available() > 0) 
{
serialA = Serial.read();
Serial.println(serialA);
}


if (mcb == LOW)         //if the mcb is in the off position
{
digitalWrite(offled, HIGH);   //turn off the OFF LED
digitalWrite(onled, LOW);     //turns off the ON LED
Serial.println('0');          //send MCB position off to android
delay(800);  
}  
else
{
digitalWrite(offled, LOW);    //turn off the OFF LED
digitalWrite(onled, HIGH);    //turns off the ON LED
Serial.println('1');          //sends MCB position on to android
delay(800); 
} 


if (tam == HIGH)         //if Tamper is button is released-This is a safe to operate       feature                 HIGH is open switch
{
int y;                        //sets up a variable y
y = offsub();                //Calls the subroutine offsub  
while(digitalRead(reset) == HIGH) //Waits for the reset to be operated
{
  digitalWrite(tamled,HIGH);   //Tamper indicator is on 

  if (mcb == LOW)            //if the mcb is safe then
  {
    digitalWrite(offled, HIGH);   //turn on the OFF LED
    digitalWrite(onled, LOW);      //turns off the ON LED
    Serial.println('2');          //tampering evident
    delay(800);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(offled, LOW);   //turn on the OFF LED
    digitalWrite(onled, HIGH);      //turns off the ON LED
    Serial.println('3');      //sends 'Tampering evidence- Danger-unable to isolate' message
    delay(800);  
   }
 }
 digitalWrite(tamled, LOW);      //Tamper indicator turns off, return to loop
 }  


 if (ems == LOW)         //if Emergency stop button is pressed                 
 {
 int y;                        //sets up a variable
 y = offsub();                 //Calls the subroutine offsub  

  while(digitalRead(reset) == HIGH) //Waits for the reset to be operated
 {
  digitalWrite(tamled, HIGH);   //turn on the Tamper LED

  if (mcb == LOW)            //if the mcb is safe then
  {
    digitalWrite(offled, HIGH);   //turn on the OFF LED
    digitalWrite(onled, LOW);      //turns off the ON LED
    Serial.println('4');        //sends emergency stop operated 
    delay(800);  
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(offled, LOW);   //turn on the OFF LED
    digitalWrite(onled, HIGH);      //turns off the ON LED
    Serial.println('5');        //sends 'emergency stop operated- Danger-unable to isolate' message
    delay(800); 
  }
 }
} 
digitalWrite(tamled, LOW);      //Tamper indicator turns off, return to loop 

if (serialA==9)         //if on button is pushed on App
{
digitalWrite(tamled, LOW);     //turn off the tamper LED
digitalWrite(onled, HIGH);    //turn on the LED
digitalWrite(offled, LOW);    //turn off the off led
int x;                        //sets up a variable
x=onsub();     //Calls the subroutine onsub
serialA==0;
}  

if (serialA==8)                 //check the status of the off button from App, if high then
{ 
digitalWrite(tamled, LOW);    //turn off the tamper led
digitalWrite(offled, HIGH);   //turn on the LED
digitalWrite(onled, LOW);     //turn off the on LED
int y;                        //sets up a variable
y = offsub();                 //Calls the subroutine offsub
serialA==0;
}
```

}

Comment: What precisely is the nature of the failure when the delay is shorter?  Often looking very specifically at the difference between what happens and what is expected provides a clue to the error mechanism.

Comment: The android app receives the serial information and displays the output when the delay is above 800. But when it is below, it does not display any change in the information. It's like it's too quick for it. The Bluetooth module is an HC06 if this helps and i'm using a galaxy s2 as the platform.
Many thanks

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "does not display any change in the information"?  Do new reports arrive with stale data?  Are no new reports received?  Corrupted ones???

Comment: I have now remedied the situation, there was a delay box in the App environment that i had not seen which was set to only process one byte every second. This was causing a backup of information that took an age to process. The delays have since been minimized and the device runs as it should. Many thanks for replying.

Comment: Please write that as an answer so that you can later accept it and the question will show as resolved.